# How to create a dynamic routing naming the routes based on props of a component in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Lets imagine that I have a component that renders multiple divs in a row.

Its pretty simple

```
if (props.hotels.length != undefined) {
    const data = props.hotels;
    const listItems = data.map((d) => (
      <div className="hotel-row">
        <Hotel name={d.name} category={d.category} image={d.image} description={d.description}/>
      </div>
    ));

    return <div className="hotel-list">{listItems}</div>;
  }
```

The above code will return a list of divs containing the content of Hotel which is quite simple.

```
    import * as React from "react";
    
    const Hotel = (props) => {
      return <p>{props.name} {props.category} {props.image} {props.description}</p>
    };

export default Hotel
```

Now, I want that in a click to each div it would redirect me to a new route.

This route would be

`/hotel/{d.name}`

I was thinking about doing something sort of this

```
<div className="hotel-row">
    <Hotel name={d.name} category={d.category} image={d.image} description={d.description} onClick={() => <Redirect to={"/"+d.name} />}/>
</div>
```

And then I want to load on that route the rest of the d.name during the mount of the component, So i can fetch from an api.

My router currently looks like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import HotelList from "../Components/HotelList";
import Count from "../Components/Count";

const Router = () => {
    const renderFor404Routes = () => <Redirect to="/" />;
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exactly component={HotelList} exact path="/" />
          <Route exactly component={Count} exact path="/count" />
          <Route path="/" exactly component={renderFor404Routes} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default withRouter(Router);
```

It would also seems to be a problem since if I want to navigate to a route like

/hotel/name , and that name doesnt exist in my database it wont fetch anything and the component would crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about doing is using dynamic routes.  Very common problem, and not too hard to do.  First, I would convert your `<Hotel>` to a `<Link>`, using the `to` prop:

```js
    const Hotel = (props) => {
      return 
        <Link to={`/${props.name}`}>
          {props.name} {props.category} {props.image} {props.description}
        </Link>
    };
```

Now you don't need the `onClick => <Redirect />`, which is very awkward.  The `Link` will do it for you.  Now, you need to set up a component that will be able to handle a dynamically generated route:

```js
// in your Switch statement:

<Route path="hotels/:hotelid" exactly component={HotelPage} />
```

So now routing to `/hotel/somehotelId` will render your `HotelPage` component.  Of course within that component, you need to get the specific id that you routed to.  Which is available as part of the `match` prop:

```js
const HotelPage = ({ match }) => {

  const { hotelId } = match.location

  // now you can make any API calls related to that hotel id,
  // or render whatever you need based on that id

}
```

This is a quick rundown. [This article](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/dynamic-pages-in-react-router/) is a more detailed explanation of the same concepts.

Answer (score 1):

React router dom lets you achieve this by using path parameters, where you can specify a route to have one like `/hotel/:name`, where the `name` is the name of the path parameter.

So, to your `<Switch>`, you can add another path like

```
<Route exact path="/hotel/:name" component={HotelByName}  />
```

Assuming you render the component `HotelByName`, react-router-dom provides the value for the specific path parameters by using the `useParams()` hook provided by react-router-dom. After which you can use it for API's in your

eg for HotelByName (hooks)

```
function HotelByName() {
  // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
  // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
  let { name } = useParams();

  //or component did mount if class based
  useEffect(() => {
     //make API request with acquired name    
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Whatever hotel data you extract */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

for class based component

```
class HotelByName extends Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
  let { name } = this.props.match.params;
  //make request with acquired name
}

  render () {
   return (
    <div>
      {/* Whatever hotel data you extract */}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```